# Required plugin could not be found

Tags: 12.04, video, codecs

I have the latest Ubuntu version.
When I try to open a `.wmv` file I got the error :

> Required plugin could not be found.
>   Python (v2.7) requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: video/x-asf-unknown decoder

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the video is using GoToMeeting codec which is not supported on Linux. I searched the Internet and found [this forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1806787).

There was a link to [this page](http://onlinemeeting.lefora.com/2009/12/08/guide-to-using-gotomeeting-on-linux/) which was provided to be helpful. I read it, as far as I understand, you need to have Wine, mplayer, w32codecs and gotomeeting codec to play it via Wine

I'm quoting the text below:

> If you want to watch a GoToMeeting video on Linux (g2m3 codec)
> You'll need to install mplayer, win32 codecs, wine, the gotomeeting codec (copy the G2M.dll codec to /usr/lib/codecs). Then run the video with WMV. You also might want to see [this post on downloading the g2m3 codec](http://onlinemeeting.lefora.com/2009/12/08/g2m3-codec-download/#post0).

Apparently, The process is as follows:

1. Install Wine with `sudo apt-get install wine`
2. Install mplayer with `sudo apt-get install mplayer`. You may want to install a front-end for mplayer. Try smplayer with `sudo apt-get install smplayer`
3. Enable the medibuntu repository by going to [this help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu#Playing%20Non-Native%20Media%20Formats).
4. After adding it, install w32codecs with `sudo apt-get install w32codecs`.
5. Then [Download the free gotoMeeting codec from here](https://www3.gotomeeting.com/codec?Portal=www.gotomeeting.com). Install the downloaded .exe file with Wine.
6. After installation, try to play the file using smplayer or mplayer.

   Don't forget to copy the `G2M.dll` file which is installed via Wine into `/usr/lib/codecs` directory. Most probably, you will find that file under `.wine` directory which is hidden in your home directory. You can search for that file using nautilus search feature.

For further info, you may want to visit these links:

- http://onlinemeeting.lefora.com/2009/12/08/guide-to-using-gotomeeting-on-linux/
- http://onlinemeeting.lefora.com/2009/12/08/g2m3-codec-download/#post0
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1806787
- And [another interesting thread on Ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1268284)

Hope this answer will help.

Comment: @Vagelism glad to help. Please leave a feedback whether it works :)

Comment: yes...I forgot.

Comment: When I try to install the gotoMeeting codec, I get: "Could not get Program Files folder"

Answer (score 1):

You need the right codecs to play .wmv winch are Windows movie, I believe. Try running the following in a console:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```