# Rhythmbox required plugin could not be found

Tags: 12.04, rhythmbox, vlc

Ubuntu 12.04 contains Rhythmbox and a video player. These tend to give me an error when I try to play, say, an .mp3 file.

```
Required plugin not found: Python (v2.7) requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3) decoder
```

Apparently, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189811/required-plugin-could-not-be-found) is one way of solving the problem, but it seems a little long winded. Is it better to just install a new (and "complete") copy of Rhythmbox? I know that other OSs like Zorin has no issues with playing media files.

(Alternatively, VLC player might be better but I don't have a good internet connection on my Linux computer at the moment.)

Comment: use the answer in the link you gave - http://askubuntu.com/a/189813/14356  i.e. install ubuntu-restricted-extras  - this will install all the codecs you need for mp3 as well as many other music types.

Answer (score 2):

Installing restricted extras should fix it:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

But if not (I also have been having troubles with Rthythmbox recently), you could switch to [Banshee](http://banshee.fm/).

Comment: I've installed both `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and `ubuntu-restricted-addons`, but I still get the same error.